# What type of argument should be used to take a method as input?

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to declare a method that takes another method as argument, so that the caller can write:

```
myClass.LoadCode(SomeClass.AnyMethod);
```

Inside the method, I'm directly looking at the method declarations and the IL code of it, so I'm actually only interested in the `Method` property (of type `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`) of the passed argument.

I have tried:

```
public Task LoadCode(Delegate method)
{
    return LoadCode(method, method.Method); // Internal method
}
```

but that requires that the caller does something like:

```
compiler.LoadCode(new Func<int, int, bool>(SomeClass.AMethodThatTakesTwoIntsAndReturnsBoolean));
```

I also tried:

```
public Task<T> LoadCode<T>(T method)
        where T : Delegate
    {
        return LoadCode(method, method.Method);
    }
```

to no avail,

```
compiler.LoadCode<Func<int, int, bool>>(SomeClass.AMethodThatTakesTwoIntsAndReturnsBoolean);
```

isn't much better either.

How do I declare a method that takes another method (or an untyped delegate) as argument, without having to explicitly specify its type/argument list?

Comment: Do you realise that syntax such as `SomeClass.AnyMethod` is in fact a "method group"? It could represent _many_ overloads that all have the same name.

Comment: @Sweeper: Good point. In fact, I didn't realize that. Not sure how I would want that to be distinguished by the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a workaround with the use of strings

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadCode(typeof(SomeClass), nameof(SomeClass.SomeMethod));
        }

        static void LoadCode(Type type, string methodName)
        {
            var methods = type.GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == methodName).ToList();
            if (methods.Count == 0) 
            {
                // not a method
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {

        }
        public void SomeMethod(object o)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was considering that earlier as well, but using strings is prone to cause user errors.

Comment: yeah, but I think it could be resolved by creating meaningful exception types and messages

Comment: Yes, you can use reflection. However, it's not good for performance.